# installation jupyterlab-sql on jupyterlab doesn't work

Tags: installation, jupyter-lab

I followed the doc to install  jupyterlab-sql but I don't get the SQL launcher in jupyterlab.

```
jupyter labextension list
```

returns

```
JupyterLab v2.1.0
Known labextensions:
   app dir: c:\users\loicm\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab
        @jupyterlab/toc v0.6.0 enabled   X
        jupyterlab-sql v0.3.3 enabled   X

   The following extension are outdated:
        @jupyterlab/toc
        jupyterlab-sql

   Consider running "jupyter labextension update --all" to check for updates.
```

and `jupyter labextension update --all`
returns

```
An error occured.
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

**What can I do to get the SQL launcher to work in jupyterlab?**
Yours sincerely
Loïc

Answer (score 0):

Same problem occurs after I updated jupyterlab to 2.x
If you check the github page of these extensions, you'll find they only work on jupyterlab 1.x, 2.x is not supported maybe because it was just released.